# Laravel 4: How to get the page number of paginated data?

Tags: pagination, laravel-4

I'm trying to create a forum with Laravel 4. I use some pagination links on topics in order to have just 30 posts per pages.

I have a page displaying all posts written by a specific user. My wish is to have a link on each of these posts redirecting to the topic's page corresponding to the post ID.

This is an example of the link I wish to have: `/forum/topic/my-topic-slug?page=x`

But I don't know how to retrieve the page number ("`x`") of a post...

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/pagination) relative to the pagination in Laravel. You can see that there is a bunch of helpful methods :

```
getCurrentPage
getLastPage
getPerPage
getTotal
getFrom
getTo
count
```

In your case, you should use the `getCurrentPage` [method](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Pagination.Paginator.html#238-246) just like this : `$paginator->getCurrentPage()`

Comment: This isn't what I need. I was expecting something like a function or a method taking the post ID as argument and returning the topic's page number where the post is displayed. For example, if I have 30 posts displayed per pages and 40 posts in a specific topic (posts ID are from 1 to 40), I would do `GetPostPage(35)` (35 is the post ID) and it would return "2" because post ID 35 is displayed on the 2nd page.

Comment: @Flobesst did you manage to accomplish this? Looking for something similar.

Comment: @TerryHarvey nope, I had to create a function myself. My function is calculating how many posts exist before my `post_id` and then it shows the page number like that:
`$page = ceil(($postsBefore + 1) / 30);`

Comment: @Flobesst That's what I was going to do. Thanks anyway!